# How was holomorphic function (local) restricted to special conformal group (global) in 2d conformal transformation?

Tags: differential-geometry, group-theory, definition, conformal-field-theory, mathematics

An example could be found on [this pdf file](http://www.ift.uni.wroc.pl/%7Epaulina/download/CFT/L1.pdf) and the discussion was the 2d conformal transformation. Usually, the conformal transformation was derived locally such that the local conformal transformations are the space of (the all) holomorphic functions

$$f(z).$$

However, for the global conformal transformation, the (Di Francesco Mathieu Senechal section 5.1.2) stated that

> the mappings must be invertible, and

> must map the whole plane into itself (more precisely the Riemann sphere, i.e., the complex plan plus the point at infinity)

Somehow, those two condition restricted the space of the holomorphic function to just $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

$$f(z)= \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, \text{ with } ad -bc =1$$

I think I saw the derivation somewhere (about the fundamental domain) but did not recall how those result was derived. Also, I'm a bit confused of how this $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ might connect with the $l_{-1}, l_0, l_1$ generators.

How was holomorphic function (local) restricted to special conformal group (global) in 2d conformal transformation?

Comment: Similar question on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/118074/11127